# Why does my website's shortened links work the 2nd time but not the 1st?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, twitter

The links that I shorten with a url shortener like tiny url cause a redirect loop the 1st time but the second time it works currectly.

**Possible causes:**

- Twitter post adding something to the end of the url
- Using url shortener might be the cause
- htaccess code may not be working for this particular situation
- link is made in php file as a variable

htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
DefaultLanguage en-US
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ServerSignature Off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index_error.php [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
#--removes .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=(.*)
RewriteRule ^([1-9][0-9]*)/([-.,_0-9a-zA-z]*)\.html$  job_details.php?query_string=$1&action=%1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([1-9][0-9]*)/([-.,_0-9a-zA-z]*)\.html$  job_details.php?query_string=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^article_cat_([1-9][0-9]*)\.html$  article.php?cat_path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^article_([1-9][0-9]*)\.html$  article.php?article_id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^mobile/([1-9][0-9]*)/([-.,_0-9a-zA-z]*)\.html$  mobile/job_details.php?query_string=$1 [L]

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: Hhhmm, "tinyurl" does appear to do something strange with the redirect - it looks like there is a secondary redirect, since the HTTP Referer is replaced. However, once the (301 permanent) redirect is _cached_ then it behaves like any other 301 redirect and passes the Referer. However, this still shouldn't cause a "redirect loop" (presumably you are getting an error?) - unless you are perhaps checking the HTTP_REFERER or something?

Comment: Just to add to my above comment, with respect to `tinyurl.com`... When you first follow a shortened link it actually loads a page at `tinyurl.com` and then triggers a 302. Only when you visit the shortened link a 2nd time does it perform a 301 permanent redirect (possibly based on cookies)? `bit.ly` does not do this.

Comment: The webpage has a redirect loop. The url ends up with /<numbervariable>/index.html

Comment: Please post the contents of your .htaccess file. Do you perform any URL rewriting yourself?